# Optimization on huge set of input

Tags: php, optimization, 32-bit, multiplication, execution-time

I need to find the **SUMMATION** of **Si * Ci** (for i in range of 1 to n).

Following are the constraints:

1 ≤ n ≤ 10^6 
1 ≤ si ≤ 10^6 
1 ≤ ci ≤ 10^6

Here is my code.

```
<?php 
    for($i = 0; $i < $n; $i++){
        $total += ($s[$i] * $c[$i]);
    } 
?>
```

However, the code runs out of time for high input values(upto 10 ^ 6).

How to add such huge numbers with proper optimisation techniques without exceeding the execution time.

Comment: http://www.xarg.org/2010/04/optimizing-integer-multiplication/

Answer (score 2):

You can increase the max execution time using `set_time_limit`

Read more here: http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php

> set_time_limit — Limits the maximum execution time
>
> bool set_time_limit ( int $seconds )

If you set it to zero it will run forever until the script finishes execution or it is interrupted manually.  Place this at the top of your script to do that:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

Update:

Use a language other than PHP.

Comment: No. I want an optimized technique to solve it. I need to know whether I can solve with a fast optimal solution.

Comment: PHP might not be the best choice for optimizing it then based on your code.  PHP has the BC Math functions but not sure if those are any faster: http://php.net/manual/en/ref.bc.php

Comment: I'd suggest trying a different language to accomplish what you want.

Answer (score 1):

There are few aspects you should take care:

## Execution Time

These operations could take lots of time, so you have to change request time limit:

```
set_time_limit(0);
```

## Usage of built in function for map/reduce

PHP offers some map/reduce functions for such operations. One is `array_map()` and another is `array_reduce()`

```
function multiply($s, $c) {
  return $s * $c;
}
function sum($carry, $item)
{
    $carry += $item;
    return $carry;
}


$result = array_reduce(array_map('multiply', $s, $c), 'sum');
```

Of couse you can use anonymous functions as callbacks.

## Precision / Overflow

Depending on you data you should take care of capacity/precision problems. In this case take a look at `bcmath` extension and `bcmul()` `bcadd()` functions.

Comment: tried map/reduce. didn't work on huge sets. I think I will have to look for another programming language.

Comment: `PHP`is really not the best choice for such kind operations, but it has some functionality if one has to do in in `PHP`

Comment: could you provide a code snippet to do so in any other language that can get it done

Comment: @SankalpTambe It depends on language. But the problems are the same in all languages.